# Why is my goroutine not executed?

Tags: go

I'm learning Go and I wanted to try goroutines and channels.

Here's my code:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){

messages := make(chan string,3)

messages <- "one"
messages <- "two"
messages <- "three"

go func(m *chan string) {
    fmt.Println("Entering the goroutine...")
    for {
        fmt.Println(<- *m)
    }
}(&messages)

fmt.Println("Done!")
}
```

And here's the result:

```
Done!
```

I don't understand why my goroutine is never executed. The "Entering the goroutine" is not printed and I don't have any error message.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The fact is that your goroutine starts, but is ended before doing anything because your program stop right after printing `Done!`: execution of goroutines is independant of the main program, but will be stopped at the same than the program. So basically, you need some process to make the program wait for them. It could be another channel waiting for a number of messages, a `sync.WaitGroup`, or other tricks.

You should read the excellent [post about concurrency in go](http://blog.golang.org/go-concurrency-patterns-timing-out-and) in the golang blog.

Answer (score 12):

Your Goroutine doesn't have enough time to execute, as the main function exits after printing `Done!`.

You need to do something to make the program wait for the Goroutine.

The easiest way is to add a `time.Sleep()` to the end.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    messages := make(chan string, 3)

    messages <- "one"
    messages <- "two"
    messages <- "three"

    go func(m *chan string) {
        fmt.Println("Entering the goroutine...")
        for {
            fmt.Println(<-*m)
        }
    }(&messages)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Done!")
}
```

> Entering the goroutine...
>   one
>   two
>   three
>   Done!

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/zuVbmwvg68)

While this works, it's recommended to use channels, or functions from the `sync` package, in addition to goroutines, to synchronize concurrent code.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    messages := make(chan string, 3)
    go func(m chan string) {
        defer close(m)
        fmt.Println("Entering the goroutine...")
        messages <- "one"
        messages <- "two"
        messages <- "three"
    }(messages)
    for message := range messages {
        fmt.Println("received", message)
    }
    fmt.Println("Done!")
}
```

> Entering the goroutine...
>   received one
>   received two
>   received three
>   Done!

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Z1mBG-8t40)

Comment: Sleeping works, but is the worst solution possible. It is next to useless in real situations.

Comment: @Elwinar, yes, but it demonstrates why the OP wasn't seeing what they expected.