# Why don't the GO routines start?

Tags: go

I wrote a simple GO program that should start 3 GO routines. However, the GO routines don't start.

Please note that the situation is not identical to the one describer within this post :

[Why is my goroutine not executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425987/why-is-my-goroutine-not-executed)

The program should wait for the GO routines to end their execution... Thus, the program should wait forever (since the routines never stop).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    fmt.Print("Starting 3 clients\n")

    for i:=0; i<3; i++ {

        client := func(inName string) {

            fmt.Printf("Client <%s> started\n", inName)

            wg.Add(1)
            conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":8000")
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("[%s] Error while connecting to the server: %s", inName, err.Error())
                os.Exit(1)
            }

            n := 0
            sleepDuration, _ := time.ParseDuration("2s")
            for {
                message := fmt.Sprintf("[%s] > message %d\n", inName, n)
                fmt.Printf("%s", message)
                _, err := conn.Write([]byte(message))
                if nil != err {
                    fmt.Sprintf("[%s] Error while writing data to the socket: %s", inName, err.Error())
                    os.Exit(1)
                }
                time.Sleep(sleepDuration)
                n++
            }
        }

        name := fmt.Sprintf("Client%d", i)
        fmt.Printf("Starting client <%s>...\n", name)
        go client(name)
        fmt.Print("Done\n")
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Result:

```
Starting 3 clients
Starting client <Client0>...
Done
Starting client <Client1>...
Done
Starting client <Client2>...
Done
```

Comment: You **must** call wg.Add(1) from _outside_ of the goroutine. Otherwise wg.Wait() might not (in your case: does not) see the Add(1).

Comment: Putting `wg.Add(1)` inside goroutine is a race condition. You don't know whether the those `Add` have been executed when `wg.Wait()` is called. And you forgot to call `Done()` in goroutine.

Comment: All right, I understand. This tool acts as a simple counter. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example for sync.WaitGroup correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208725/example-for-sync-waitgroup-correct)

Comment: @DenisKertios is the given answer solved your problem? If it does, you may accept it.

Answer (score 3):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208725/example-for-sync-waitgroup-correct) solution says:

> It is important that the wg.Add() happens before the go statement to
>   prevent race conditions. The following would also be correct:

So, you need to take out `wg.Add(1)` off inside of go routine itself and call it just before starting go routines. Also, call `defer wg.Done()` at the start of the function, so that, it will decrements the WaitGroup counter by one. Take a look at the code below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    fmt.Print("Starting 3 clients\n")

    for i:=0; i<3; i++ {

        client := func(inName string) {

            defer wg.Done() // added this line

            fmt.Printf("Client <%s> started\n", inName)

            conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":8000")
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("[%s] Error while connecting to the server: %s", inName, err.Error())
                os.Exit(1)
            }

            n := 0
            sleepDuration, _ := time.ParseDuration("2s")
            for {
                message := fmt.Sprintf("[%s] > message %d\n", inName, n)
                fmt.Printf("%s", message)
                _, err := conn.Write([]byte(message))
                if nil != err {
                    fmt.Sprintf("[%s] Error while writing data to the socket: %s", inName, err.Error())
                    os.Exit(1)
                }
                time.Sleep(sleepDuration)
                n++
            }
        }

        name := fmt.Sprintf("Client%d", i)
        fmt.Printf("Starting client <%s>...\n", name)
        wg.Add(1) // moved this line
        go client(name)
        fmt.Print("Done\n")
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```